.replace() method not replacing within for loop but works manually
This is my code:
numbers = {'1' : '۱', '2' : '۲', '3' : '۳', '4' : '۴', '5' : '۵', '6' : '۶', '7' : '۷', '8' : '۸', '9' : '۹', '0' : '۰', ',': '٬', '.': '.'}
pricing = ['12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,543', '124,689']

I'm going to replace each character with its equivalent in the numbers:
for n in numbers:
    for price in pricing:
        new = price.replace(n, numbers[n])

But when I run, it doesn't replace any characters, but if I run like this, it replaces:
new = price.replace('8', '۸')

What's my issue?
Edit1
>>> numbers = {'1' : '۱', '2' : '۲', '3' : '۳', '4' : '۴', '5' : '۵', '6' : '۶', '7' : '۷', '8' : '۸', '9' : '۹', '0' : '۰', ',': '٬', '.': '.'}
>>> pricing = ['12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,543', '124,689']
>>> new_list = []
>>> for n in numbers:
...     for price in pricing:
...         new = price.replace(n, numbers[n])
...         new_list.append(new)
...
>>> new_list
['۱2,4۱2,424,2۱4', '۱24,۱24,2۱4', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,543', '۱24,689', '1۲,41۲,4۲4,۲14', '1۲4,1۲4,۲14', '۲43,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,543', '1۲4,689', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '24۳,۳6۳', '۳,۳6۳,46۳', '6,789,54۳', '124,689', '12,۴12,۴2۴,21۴', '12۴,12۴,21۴', '2۴3,363', '3,363,۴63', '6,789,5۴3', '12۴,689', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,۵43', '124,689', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,3۶3', '3,3۶3,4۶3', '۶,789,543', '124,۶89', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,۷89,543', '124,689', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,7۸9,543', '124,6۸9', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,78۹,543', '124,68۹', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,543', '124,689', '12٬412٬424٬214', '124٬124٬214', '243٬363', '3٬363٬463', '6٬789٬543', '124٬689', '12,412,424,214', '124,124,214', '243,363', '3,363,463', '6,789,543', '124,689']


Of course it does the replacement.  But it saves the modified string in new, which you keep overwriting.  You need to SAVE the changed strings in a new list.

@TimRoberts I edited the question with the new changes. Do you please check?

Yes, because you're doing them in the wrong order.  You're processing the strings 11 times, producing a new result each time.  The OUTER loop needs to be pricing, then the INNER loop runs through numbers  and produces a single result.

Copy your prices to a new list.
newprice = []
for price in pricing:
    newprice.append(price)
    for n in numbers:
        newprice[-1] = newprice[-1].replace(n, numbers[n])

Or even use the Python translate function:
newprice = []
for price in pricing:
    newprice.append( price.translate(''.maketrans(numbers)) )

